# Setting user picked date from DatePicker to Calendar

Tags: java, android

So I need for user to select date from DatePicker Dialog and then when he selects date I want it to be shown on Calendar. For example, if user selects 01/01/2016 I want that date to be shown as some red marked date.

Here's my code:

```
displayDatumaDodajPisaniIspit = (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.displayDatumaDodajPisaniIspit);
                            set = (Button)dialog. findViewById(R.id.set);
                            set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    new DatePickerDialog(HomeScreen.this, listener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                                }
                            });
```

And the listener

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        displayDatumaDodajPisaniIspit.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
        calendarView.setDateSelected();
    }

};
```

I don't have idea how to start with it. Tried with some methods in listener but it didn't work.

Comment: You should use the setDate methods provided by CalendarView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setDate%28long%29

Comment: I don't have setDate, I have setDateSelected, setCurrentDate, setMaximumDate, setMinimumDate, setSelectedDate

Comment: Then you are not being specific which CalendarView you are using. This is the CalendarView documentation: developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Comment: Sorry I haven't mentioned, I'm using https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first convert the chosen date into millis -

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

    long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

and then set the date in your `CalendarView` like this -

```
calendarView.setDate(millis);
```

As you mentioned you are using `MaterialCalendarView`, then I guess you can use -

```
calendarView.setSelectedDate(CalendarDay.from(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm using https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview , not the stock CalendatView, so setDate is not working for me

Comment: What is the signature of setDateSelected() ?

Comment: Calendar calendar, boolean selected

Comment: Edited my answer for MaterialCalendarView. Hope it helps !!